# SQL Server lock table with guaranteed release

Tags: sql-server, transactions, locking

I have an ASP.NET web application that has a critical spot where a user reserves some number for himself.

What happens is:

1. There is a table where 'last_box_number' is stored, i.e. 3044
2. Application reads this number and computes some barcodes with it, for example it needs the next 100 numbers, each numbered from 3045 to 3144.
3. Application stores these numbers with additional data in the database and updates the 'last_box_number' to 3144. This is performed within a transaction.

The problem is that between 1) and 3) there is a possibility that another user would do the same and would read 3044 from unmodified table, so I need to lock the table with 'last_box_number' from reading, but if the first user fails (disconnects or whatever else bad happens) the table would remain locked.

I am not very familiar with the SQL Server locking mechanism, so I need a guaranteed lock release after some timeout.

Anyway, any advice of the best way to implement the aforementioned is welcome.

**UPDATE:**
OK, here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sscc_numbers](
[gs1prefix] [bigint] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[rangestart] [int] NOT NULL,
[lastnumber] [int] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ssccs](
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[sscc] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[clientid] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[referencenum] [int] NOT NULL,
... other fields
```

A user1 wants to book 10 numbers (referencenum) so he queries the sscc_numbers table and gets 'lastnumber', for example 6.

then it starts its business and generates 10 new SSCC numbers with reference numbers from 7 to 16 (thinking that the last used number is 6). After he's done he inserts the relevant data for those 10 numbers into the sscc table. Then he runs `update sscc_numbers set lastnumber=16 ...`

Now the scenario I want to avoid - imagine a second user user2 queries the sscc_numbers while user1 is busy and gets that same number 6 from the sscc_numbers.  Then, after user2 finishes he wouldn't be able to insert his data into the ssccs table because he uses duplicate reference numbers.

User1 from the other hand may disconnect, process data for too long, etc. If I locked the sscc_numbers table for 10-15 seconds that wouldn't be a problem, but after that, he would need to reset his work and get a new 'lastnumber'

It would be great if the amount of new records was known beforehand, but it can change from time to time, and it is absolutely essential that those reference numbers were consistent and unique.

Comment: To me it seems there should be an alternate solution that doesn't involve locking your tables at all. But I can't fully understand your requirement to enable me to answer. If you can add a simple example with some schema for the tables and dummy data, I will have a look in more detail.

Comment: once the values are reserved, can they be un-reserved? and what happens to that range if that happens? should it be available again or will that be ignored going forward, leaving you with gaps in your box number list?

Comment: If we exclude the possibility of a better solution with more information, then you are most likely looking for application locks ([mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Semaphores_vs._mutexes)). This guide is for sql server 2005, but the procedures are the same: [Application Locks (or Mutexes) in SQL Server 2005 - Mladen Prajdić](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005), and [**`sp_getapplock`** - docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql)

Comment: No, the numbers cannot be 'un-reserved' but they actually get reserved only if the data is supplied, user should have 10-15 seconds for processing and return the information otherwise he should start again. Only after the information is inserted, the 'last used number' should actually be updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this... My personal preference would be to use something similar to a shopping cart. A user loads their cart (temporarily reserves some portion of inventory) and then either checks out, creating an actual order and reducing actual inventory... or abandons the cart making those items available to another shopper.

So, I'd create a table that simply reserves a particular box to a particular session and doesn't allow any other session to use it until the original session either commits the final step in the transaction (making it permanently unavailable) or rolls back frees up the box number for the next user.